# Iterate through the Node using for-each variable dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Using XSLT, I have to iterate through the list of XML elements (start_date, end_date, value) dynamically at run-time since the number of attributes present inside 'variables' is not constant. Sample below

```
     <attributes name="variables">
        <attribute name="start_date_1">2013-09-01</attribute>
        <attribute name="end_date_1">2014-09-01</attribute>
        <attribute name="value_1">Y</attribute>
        <attribute name="start_date_2">2013-09-01</attribute>
        <attribute name="end_date_2">2014-09-01</attribute>
        <attribute name="value_2">Y</attribute>
        <attribute name="start_date_3">2013-09-01</attribute>
        <attribute name="end_date_3">2014-09-01</attribute>
        <attribute name="value_3">Y</attribute>
        4,5,6,.....
    </attributes>
```

The number of times the fields repeat (start_date, end_date, value) changes based on XML.
I tried For-Each using 'position()' and used the 'concat' method.
But unable to fetch the values.

Comment: 1. What is the expected output? 2. Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. 3. Do they always come in groups of 3?

Comment: yes. they always come in set of 3.

Comment: Good, that makes it easy. Now you just need to address #1 and #2.